# How to do this table in Latex using longtable?

Tags: tables, longtable

I want to do the following table in Latex using the longtable package:

[image]

The codes that I have right now does 5 columns and I don't know how to merge the two columns unfortunately. How do I reproduce the table in the figure?

So far I am using the following codes:

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
  & WITS  &ASUS  &  &  \\ \hline
 Frequency of Substance Use & Past 7 days & Past 30 days &Past 6 months  & Lifetime  \\ \hline
 Alcohol&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 Marijuana&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 Cocaine&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 Opiates&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 Heroin&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 Amphetamines&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 Hallucinogens&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 Inhalants&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 Barbiturates&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 Sedatives&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
 Tranquilizers&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

**EDIT:** I made an edit to my codes following the comments below:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \caption{WITS and ASUS Substance Use Disorder.} \label{tab:long} \\
        \hline \multicolumn{2}{c}{WITS}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{ASUS}\\ \hline
        Frequency of Substance Use & Past 7 days & Past 30 days &Past 6 months  & Lifetime  \\ \hline
        Alcohol&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Marijuana&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Cocaine&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Opiates&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Heroin&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Amphetamines&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Hallucinogens&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Inhalants&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Barbiturates&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Sedatives&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
        Tranquilizers&  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
```

I am getting the output:

[image]

How do I get WITS and ASUS between the columns 2 and 5?

Comment: As a starting point: replace `\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|}` with `\begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|l|l|}` and `\end{tabular}\end{table}` with `\end{longtable}`.

Comment: Simply use, for the first row: `\multicolumn{2}{c}{WITS}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{ASUS}\\ \hline`

Comment: @Bernard I made an edit. I am having trouble aligning WITS and ASUS between the columns 2-3 and 4-5, respectively. If you know what I mean

Comment: You forgot to add a `&` at the beginning of the row (and in my previous comment, I thought I had typed it, but forgot to check).

Comment: Remove the `center` environment around the `longtable`.

Comment: This part works for ASUS column but not the WITS side: \hline \multicolumn{2}{c}{WITS}& &\multicolumn{2}{c}{ASUS}\\ \hline

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you refer to the missing vertical lines? If so, try `&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{WITS}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{ASUS}\\ \hline` or even better: Use a table layout that uses no vertical line at all and just a few well-placed horizontal lines in order to increase the readability of your table.